# Nginx ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS by adjusting WordPress Permalinks | 301 Error Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wordpress, 301-redirect, nginx, ubuntu, permalinks

- *OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (having my own VPS)*
- *WebServer:  Nginx/1.18.0*
- *MySQL: mysql  Ver 8.0.22 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)*
- *WordPress: 5.6*

When I change the **Permalinks** option in WordPress ([ScreenShot: */wp-admin/options-permalink.php*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsTP0.jpg)) from the default (*?p=123*) to */%postname%/* (the last option on the page) I get the following error: ***"ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"*** with status code **301** **only for the Homepage** *(so directly example.com)*, all other pages working perfect, even the new permalink option is working right such that the default blog is accessible by: */hello-world/* directly.

Any idea why? This was the last thing to do such that my Server was finished, spent more time on this small bug than everything else lol. *Note: I have disabled every plugin and except nginx cache which I use to clear the server-side caching. Also I visit the website incognito.*

I followed this tutorial: [SpinUp WP (I did everything till and including CH6)](https://spinupwp.com/hosting-wordpress-yourself-nginx-security-tweaks-woocommerce-caching-auto-server-updates/).
Hereby my NGINX Settings:

**NGINX Config File** (I have changed username to omar, for privacy reasons):

```
user omar;
worker_processes 6;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        keepalive_timeout 15;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;
        client_max_body_size 64m;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;


        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 5;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Cache Settings
        ##
        fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
        add_header Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;


        ##
        # Security
        ##
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" always;
        add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "origin-when-cross-origin" always;



        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            server_name _;
            return 444;
        }
}
```

**Config file of example.com** (I have changed username to omar and domain to example.com, privacy reasons):

```
fastcgi_cache_path /home/omar/example.com/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=example.com:100m inactive=60m;

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

server_name example.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

access_log /home/omar/example.com/logs/access.log;
error_log /home/omar/example.com/logs/error.log;

root /home/omar/example.com/public/;
index index.php;

set $skip_cache 0;
# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
set $skip_cache 1;
}
if ($query_string != "") {
set $skip_cache 1;
}

# Don't cache uris containing the following segments
if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
set $skip_cache 1;
}

# Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
set $skip_cache 1;
}

if ($request_uri ~* "/(cart|checkout|my-account)/*$")
{
set $skip_cache 1;
}

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
fastcgi_cache example.com;
fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
}
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

server_name www.example.com;;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name example.com www.example.com;;

return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

If I need more things to show just tell me, I will show more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alhamdulillah, I found the answer. It was all due to trying to be perfectionist Muslim, I had capital letters in the URL inside: */wp-admin/options-general.php*.
All praises to God (Alhamdulillah), solved, by making all the letters lowercase. With God his will (in shaa Allah) it will help you brothers and non-brothers.